# Is it possible to set up constraints and objects outside of the ViewController file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to programming without the use of storyboards. What I am trying to do is move the code that is responsible for initializing the UIView and constraints, from there I want too put those in another file.

Ideally, I would like to have one call

**view.addSubview(loginControllerObjects(frame: view.frame))**

from my viewDidLoad() that calls that separate file and sets up the objects in their appropriate places in order to keep my ViewController clutter free.

I have worked out most of the problem but it seems as if my function setUpInputContainer() is giving me "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" error. It is suggested that its due to its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies. Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

**App Delegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let homeViewController = ViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

}
```

**View Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    view.addSubview(loginControllerContraints(frame: view.frame))
}

}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

**LoginControllerContraints**

```
class loginControllerContraints: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 61, g: 91, b: 151)
    setUpInputContainer()
    addSubview(inputsContainerView)

}

let inputsContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    let red = UIColor.red
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.layer.backgroundColor = red.cgColor
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}()

var inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

func setUpInputContainer() {
    //Needs x, y, height, and width constraints for INPUTCONTAINER
    inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor = inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
    inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.isActive = true


}

//Required do not touch
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you call `setUpInputContainer` before you add `inputsContainerView` to `loginControllerContraints`.

To fix it, add `inputsContainerView` to `loginControllerContraints` before adding any constraints of `inputsContainerView` . Replace `init` method of `loginControllerContraints` with the code below.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 61, g: 91, b: 151)
    addSubview(inputsContainerView)
    setUpInputContainer()
}
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the clear response.

Comment: Welcome @ChandlerLong ;)